# Cannot Read property "textContent" of undefined. Console showing an error, but code still works?

Tags: javascript

When I run the code below I get an error in the console saying "Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined". The strange part is the code actually works, however I do not understand why this error is shown. I am new to programming and I apologize for any issues with my code. Thank you in advance for any help.

The error points to the last line of the addDates function. However if you console.log(dayNumY[i].textContent) before the error line, it returns the letter "Y" 7 times just as it should. The following line sets the textContent with dates, as I expect it to, but still shows the error.

Here is my code (minus the CSS), again apologies and thank you:

```js
const date = new Date;
const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
const day = date.getDay();
const dayNumber = date.getDate();

var wDisplayDay = document.querySelectorAll(".wDisplayDay");
var dayNumY = document.querySelectorAll(".dayNumY");
var dayNameX = document.querySelectorAll(".dayNameX");


function numOfDays(){                   

    const oneDay = 24*60*60*1000
    let start = new Date(date.getFullYear(), month - 1, dayNumber);
    let end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, 1)
    const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((start - end) / oneDay));

    return diffDays
}

function addDates(){
    var currentDays = numOfDays() + dayNumber;
   for(var i = 0; i < currentDays; i++){
        console.log(dayNumY[i].textContent);
        dayNumY[i].textContent = dayNumber + Number([i]); 
    }
}
addDates();
```

```css
.wDisplayDay {
    float: left;
    width: 39px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
.wDisplayDay h1, .wDisplayDay h3 {
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="weekDisplay">
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

I have also created a codepen just in case I messed something up with this post: 
https://codepen.io/Lou-Kaz/pen/bGdXKQm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error occurs because you try to access an array element which simply doesnt exist.

In your for loop you should use dayNumY.length as upper limit and not currentdays.

dayNumY has 7 elements and currentDays is 31. So you cant access any element with an index above 6.

```js
const date = new Date;
const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
const day = date.getDay();
const dayNumber = date.getDate();

var wDisplayDay = document.querySelectorAll(".wDisplayDay");
var dayNumY = document.querySelectorAll(".dayNumY");
var dayNameX = document.querySelectorAll(".dayNameX");


function numOfDays(){                   

    const oneDay = 24*60*60*1000
    let start = new Date(date.getFullYear(), month - 1, dayNumber);
    let end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, 1)
    const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((start - end) / oneDay));

    return diffDays
}

function addDates(){
    var currentDays = numOfDays() + dayNumber;
   for(var i = 0; i < dayNumY.length; i++){
        console.log(dayNumY[i].textContent);
        dayNumY[i].textContent = dayNumber + Number([i]); 
    }
}
addDates();
```

```html
<section class="container">
        <div class="weekDisplay">
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wDisplayDay">
                <h3 class="dayNameX">x</h3>
                <h1 class="dayNumY">y</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: this worked and made sense right away, thank you very much that error was driving me crazy.

Comment: Please upvote my answer and mark it as accepted so others can find it more easily :) @Lucas